# Msp430 I²C single write-read example

Tags: i2c, msp430

I've been trying to use an I²C bus between a MSP430G2553 launchpad and ITG-3200 gyroscope breakout. Here is the [Launchpad datasheet and user guide](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430g2553) and the [ITG-3200 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Gyro/PS-ITG-3200-00-01.4.pdf). The ITG-3200 uses a repeated start to read from a specific register. But not necessarily.  After checking the example code on the Arduino (I checked the data flow on buses with an oscilloscope) I realised that even with a Stop-Start condition it should work. What I'm trying to do is to accomplish this on the MSP Launchpad.

I'm using two I²C examples provided from TI msp430g2xx3_uscib0_i2c_04 (single read) and msp430g2xx3_uscib0_i2c_06 (single write). I combined these two sets of code and came up with code for my ITG-3200 which uses a write operation followed by a read for reading it's registers. Here is the code:

```
#include <msp430.h>


int TXByteCtr = 1;
unsigned char PRxData;                     // Pointer to RX data
int Rx = 0;
unsigned char WHO_AM_I = 0x00;

void init_I2C(void);
void Transmit(void);
void Receive(void); 
int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  init_I2C();
  while(1){
  //Transmit process
  Rx = 0;
  Transmit();
  while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent

  //Receive process
  Rx = 1;
  Receive();
  while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
  }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The USCI_B0 data ISR is used to move received data from the I2C slave
// to the MSP430 memory. It is structured such that it can be used to receive
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
{
  if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve?
  PRxData = UCB0RXBUF;                       // Get RX data
  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
  }

  else{                                     // Master Transmit
  if (TXByteCtr)                            // Check TX byte counter
  {
      UCB0TXBUF = WHO_AM_I;                     // Load TX buffer
      TXByteCtr--;                            // Decrement TX byte counter
  }
  else
  {
      UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
      IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX int flag
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
  }
 }

}

void init_I2C(void) {
  _DINT();
  IE2 |= UCB0RXI             //Enable RX interrupt
  IE2 |= UCB0TXIE;                          // Enable TX interrupt
  while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);               // Ensure stop condition got sent
  UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
  UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master, synchronous mode
  UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;            // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
  UCB0BR0 = 12;                             // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
  UCB0BR1 = 0;
  UCB0I2CSA = 0x69;                         // Slave Address is 069h
  UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // Clear SW reset, resume operation
}

void Transmit(void){
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
}
void Receive(void){
   UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR ;                  // Clear UCTR
   while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                    // I2C start condition
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // Start condition sent?
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
    __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
}
```

I don't really know why is this happening but SDA and SCL clocks keeps locking to 0V. I'm sure about the circuit (full with pull-up resistors) because that is working on an Arduino. Can you point out what seems to be the problem here?

Edit: It is better if i put the two examples from TI resource here aswell.

It is better if i give the two example of TI here. Here is the master RX single byte from the slave: ( msp430g2xx3_uscib0_i2c_04.c )

```
 /* --COPYRIGHT--,BSD_EX
     * Copyright (c) 2012, Texas Instruments Incorporated
     * All rights reserved.
     *
     * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
     * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
     * are met:
     *
     * *  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
     *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     *
     * *  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
     *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
     *
     * *  Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
     *    its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
     *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
     *
     * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
     * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
     * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
     * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
     * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
     * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
     * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS;
     * OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
     * WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
     * OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
     * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
     *
     *******************************************************************************
     * 
     *                       MSP430 CODE EXAMPLE DISCLAIMER
     *
     * MSP430 code examples are self-contained low-level programs that typically
     * demonstrate a single peripheral function or device feature in a highly
     * concise manner. For this the code may rely on the device's power-on default
     * register values and settings such as the clock configuration and care must
     * be taken when combining code from several examples to avoid potential side
     * effects. Also see www.ti.com/grace for a GUI- and www.ti.com/msp430ware
     * for an API functional library-approach to peripheral configuration.
     *
     * --/COPYRIGHT--*/
    //******************************************************************************
    //  MSP430G2xx3 Demo - USCI_B0 I2C Master RX single bytes from MSP430 Slave
    //
    //  Description: This demo connects two MSP430's via the I2C bus. The master
    //  reads from the slave. This is the master code. The data from the slave
    //  transmitter begins at 0 and increments with each transfer. The received
    //  data is in R5 and is checked for validity. If the received data is
    //  incorrect, the CPU is trapped and the P1.0 LED will stay on. The USCI_B0
    //  RX interrupt is used to know when new data has been received.
    //  ACLK = n/a, MCLK = SMCLK = BRCLK = default DCO = ~1.2MHz
    //
    //                                /|\  /|\
    //               MSP430G2xx3      10k  10k     MSP430G2xx3
    //                   slave         |    |        master
    //             -----------------   |    |  -----------------
    //           -|XIN  P1.7/UCB0SDA|<-|---+->|P1.7/UCB0SDA  XIN|-
    //            |                 |  |      |                 | 32kHz
    //           -|XOUT             |  |      |             XOUT|-
    //            |     P1.6/UCB0SCL|<-+----->|P1.6/UCB0SCL     |
    //            |                 |         |             P1.0|--> LED
    //
    //  D. Dang
    //  Texas Instruments Inc.
    //  February 2011
    //   Built with CCS Version 4.2.0 and IAR Embedded Workbench Version: 5.10
    //******************************************************************************
    #include <msp430.h>

    unsigned char RXData;
    unsigned char RXCompare;

    int main(void)
    {
      WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
      P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
      P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
      UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
      UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master, synchronous mode
      UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;            // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
      UCB0BR0 = 12;                             // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
      UCB0BR1 = 0;
      UCB0I2CSA = 0x069;                        // Slave Address is 048h
      UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // Clear SW reset, resume operation
      IE2 |= UCB0RXIE;                          // Enable RX interrupt
      RXCompare = 0;                            // Used to check incoming data

      while (1)
      {
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                    // I2C start condition
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // Start condition sent?
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts

      }
    }

    // USCI_B0 Data ISR
    #pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
    __interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
    {
      RXData = UCB0RXBUF;                       // Get RX data
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
    }
```

And here is the Master TX single byte to the slave ( msp430g2xx3_uscib0_i2c_04.c )

```
/* --COPYRIGHT--,BSD_EX
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Texas Instruments Incorporated
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * *  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * *  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * *  Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
 *    its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS;
 * OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
 * OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
 * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 *******************************************************************************
 * 
 *                       MSP430 CODE EXAMPLE DISCLAIMER
 *
 * MSP430 code examples are self-contained low-level programs that typically
 * demonstrate a single peripheral function or device feature in a highly
 * concise manner. For this the code may rely on the device's power-on default
 * register values and settings such as the clock configuration and care must
 * be taken when combining code from several examples to avoid potential side
 * effects. Also see www.ti.com/grace for a GUI- and www.ti.com/msp430ware
 * for an API functional library-approach to peripheral configuration.
 *
 * --/COPYRIGHT--*/
//******************************************************************************
//  MSP430G2xx3 Demo - USCI_B0 I2C Master TX single bytes to MSP430 Slave
//
//  Description: This demo connects two MSP430's via the I2C bus. The master
//  transmits to the slave. This is the master code. It continuously
//  transmits 00h, 01h, ..., 0ffh and demonstrates how to implement an I2C
//  master transmitter sending a single byte using the USCI_B0 TX interrupt.
//  ACLK = n/a, MCLK = SMCLK = BRCLK = default DCO = ~1.2MHz
//
//                                /|\  /|\
//               MSP430G2xx3      10k  10k     MSP430G2xx3
//                   slave         |    |        master
//             -----------------   |    |  -----------------
//           -|XIN  P1.7/UCB0SDA|<-|---+->|P1.7/UCB0SDA  XIN|-
//            |                 |  |      |                 |
//           -|XOUT             |  |      |             XOUT|-
//            |     P1.6/UCB0SCL|<-+----->|P1.6/UCB0SCL     |
//            |                 |         |                 |
//
//  D. Dang
//  Texas Instruments Inc.
//  February 2011
//   Built with CCS Version 4.2.0 and IAR Embedded Workbench Version: 5.10
//******************************************************************************
#include <msp430.h>

unsigned char TXData;
unsigned char TXByteCtr;

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
  UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master, synchronous mode
  UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;            // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
  UCB0BR0 = 12;                             // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
  UCB0BR1 = 0;
  UCB0I2CSA = 0x69;                         // Slave Address is 048h
  UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // Clear SW reset, resume operation
  IE2 |= UCB0TXIE;                          // Enable TX interrupt

  TXData = 0x00;                            // Holds TX data

  while (1)
  {
    TXByteCtr = 1;                          // Load TX byte counter
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
                                            // Remain in LPM0 until all data
                                            // is TX'd
    TXData++;                               // Increment data byte
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The USCIAB0TX_ISR is structured such that it can be used to transmit any
// number of bytes by pre-loading TXByteCtr with the byte count.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
{
  if (TXByteCtr)                            // Check TX byte counter
  {
    UCB0TXBUF = TXData;                     // Load TX buffer
    TXByteCtr--;                            // Decrement TX byte counter
  }
  else
  {
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
    IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX int flag
    __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the pins to the required output/input setting?

Comment: Of course, as i told you my circuit is as it's required. 1.7 to SDA and 1.6 to SCL, two 10K pull-up resistors on them. The wierd part is that these two examples are working seperately. But my code which i combined them is not working so I'm pretty sure that the problem is code based.

Comment: Yes, but did you configure the pins as output/input? You should do that in the code, not in the circuit.

Comment: I don't think that is required. Since these two pins are bus related, selecting them to USCI_B0 will do.               P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0 In TI's examples, they do exactly the same without any configuration on the pins except the selecting.

Comment: Me neither, but for SPI it is required on some controllers and I follow the rule "better just do it, then you're sure". But feel free to omit it, and let's just hope it doesn't work out bad for you.

Comment: I think SPI is a 3 wire protocol so it's in and out buses are different. I2C on the other hand, uses 2 wire connection so SDA bus works both ways. I do not think the problem lies within the pin directions because as i said earlier, two of these examples works seperately.

Comment: You're right about the different buses. Again, feel free to omit the pin configurations. I always found it to be good practice. And now, if you want to discuss this any further, please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: Oh my god.. Can't belive i made such a small mistake.. I forgot to re-declare TxByteCtr to 1 in the loop. Now it is working.

Comment: We all make basic mistakes every now and then. You should answer your own question with this solution, so that other users can benefit from it as well! ;)

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu Glad you have it working, but also double check that you removed the p1.6 led jumper.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that reading a single byte via I²C. Do not forget to connect 2 pull-up resistors on P1.6 and P1.7. These are the SDA and SCL lines on I2C bus.

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>


int TXByteCtr;
unsigned char PRxData;                     
int Rx = 0;
char WHO_AM_I = 0x00;

char itgAddress = 0x69;

void init_I2C(void);
void Transmit(void);
void Receive(void);


int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                     // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
  init_I2C();




  while(1){
      //Transmit process
      Rx = 0;
      TXByteCtr = 1;
      Transmit();
      //Receive process
      Rx = 1;
      Receive();
  }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The USCI_B0 data ISR is used to move received data from the I2C slave
// to the MSP430 memory. It is structured such that it can be used to receive
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
{
  if(Rx == 1){                              // Master Recieve?
      PRxData = UCB0RXBUF;                       // Get RX data
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);        // Exit LPM0
  }

  else{                                     // Master Transmit
      if (TXByteCtr)                            // Check TX byte counter
        {
          UCB0TXBUF = WHO_AM_I;                     // Load TX buffer
          TXByteCtr--;                            // Decrement TX byte counter
        }
        else
        {
          UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
          IFG2 &= ~UCB0TXIFG;                     // Clear USCI_B0 TX int flag
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
 }

}
void init_I2C(void) {
      UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
      UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master, synchronous mode
      UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;            // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
      UCB0BR0 = 12;                             // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
      UCB0BR1 = 0;
      UCB0I2CSA = itgAddress;                         // Slave Address is 069h
      UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // Clear SW reset, resume operation
      IE2 |= UCB0RXIE + UCB0TXIE;               //Enable RX and TX interrupt
}

void Transmit(void){
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
}
void Receive(void){
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent
        UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR ;                     // Clear UCTR
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                    // I2C start condition
        while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // Start condition sent?
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);        // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
}
```

Comment: So how did this code solve the problem? Add more detail to how it answered the question.

Comment: I only added TXByteCtr = 1; in the while loop. Appearently, i was decrementing TXByteCtr to 0 in the first iteration and since it never went back to 1, the operation was holding.